# Laravel guzzle auth not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, guzzle

There two laravel projects. I have two pages in project one (one of them is under login and password, another without them). From project two I am trying to get the content. With the page without any authentication needed everything works perfect. But I am getting just the login page working with the page with auth.
This is my code:

```
<?php
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'my_base_url',
        'timeout'  => 5.0,
        'auth' => ['login', 'password', 'digest'],
         'headers' => array('Accept'        => 'application/vnd.comay.v1.1+xml',
         'Content-Type'  => 'text/xml'),
     ]);
     $response = $client->get('/products/page2');
     echo $response->getReasonPhrase();
     $body = $response->getBody();
     echo $body;
?>
```

Comment: You're probably being redirected to the login page, as you do not have  a valid session. Login via the login page, and pass the session cookies on future requests. Or better yet, if you're in control of both projects, why not just write an API?

Comment: As @fubar suggested build API for this. You are not going to make this work reliably with guzzle. I am not going to elaborate on this, but better consider guzzle as some sort of testing lib, which you can occasionally use to fetch some things from the web..